# Where do you find info on vram on system?

Tags: vb.net

Where do you find info on vram on system? What interface, function, library can give that information?

To find out regular overall info on a computer is My.Computer.Info, but it does not list video ram and so far websearching has yielded no result.

Comment: In modern computers, the concept of a 'video ram' is quite intricate. Why do you want to access this thing? Depending on your use, there will be different approaches. I assume by vram you expect some array which holds monitors pixls?

Comment: Im making a portable launcher for a program. I need to check how much video ram the graphics card has so i can avoid potential problems in the program that the launcher launches. How do games usually check for this?

Comment: Here is the answer, this question is now closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079786/get-hardware-information-such-as-graphic-card-capabilities