# GPU SubVendor name Python

Tags: python, wmi, video-card

I'm using pythons wmi module for a lot of hardware specs of a system.

I'd like to get the Graphics card SubVendor information. Like MSI, EVGA, XFX etc.

I have not yet found a way to do this. Any suggestions?

WMI has nothing that returns this. Searching I don't see an option for specifically the SubVendor. Name returns "NVIDIA (card model)"

I don't know how GPU-Z or Speccy gets this information. Its possible though.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/q/22118174/407651?

Comment: No. Name returns "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti" and I have a EVGA card. wmi has no listing for the vendor.

Comment: Also I should of clarified GPU "subvendor". Don't think I can edit the post but thats what I'm looking for. I wonder how apps like speccy or gpu-z get the subvendor information.

Comment: Just click "Edit" to edit the question. Possibly related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1403446/can-a-gpu-forget-its-subvendor

Comment: Done, and no sadly not. Only if Speccy or GPU-Z's code was open source.