# How can I find out what graphic card a screen is connected to in C#?

Tags: c#, directx

I need to programatically find out what graphic card a screen is connected to using C#.
This information is visible in DxDiag, speccy and even in windows advanced display settings view:
[image: Speccy]

[image: DxDiag]

[image: Windows]

But how can I do this in C# myself?

Comment: i never used this myself , but maybe worth further investigation [link](https://github.com/falahati/WindowsDisplayAPI.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is code by @NielW in [C# detect which graphics card drives video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992099/c-sharp-detect-which-graphics-card-drives-video/23256412)

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
  foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
  {
    PropertyData currentBitsPerPixel = mo.Properties["CurrentBitsPerPixel"];
    PropertyData description = mo.Properties["Description"];
    if (currentBitsPerPixel != null && description != null)
    {
      if (currentBitsPerPixel.Value != null)
        System.Console.WriteLine(description.Value);
      }
    }
  }
```

There is a long talk in the link because they have issues getting multiples graphic cards' names. But this code should work and it shows all names of available graphic cards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is not quite what I'm after though.
What I need is to list my screens and see what graphic card they are connected to. Or to simplify I need to check how many screens are connected to each of the graphic cards. 
Querying WMIMonitorID class i can list the connected monitors: 
Manufacturer Model       
------------ -----       
Samsung      SyncMaster  
Samsung      SMBX2240    
Samsung      SMBX2240    
CMN          MIMO Monitor

But I need to somehow connect these with the data in Win32_VideoController, but I cannot see any connection between them.