# C# how to effectively detect which graphic card is used

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, hardware-acceleration

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939168/c-sharp-how-can-gpu-be-present-but-not-used) post I had the need to detect which graphic card is really in use.
In order to be sure to use the dedicated NVIDIA and not the integrated intel I:

1. have set to use it for global usage

[image: global usage]

2. have forced to use it for my application

[image: my application]

> **So I am pretty sure that my program is using the NVIDIA**
> also because I see the GPU usage in the task manager

---

---

---

That being said I need a way to confirm that I am using the NVIDIA and not the INTEL graphic card.

From [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992099/c-sharp-detect-which-graphics-card-drives-video/23256412) page I see a way to do it.
And following my implementation:

```
string strGraphicCards = "Graphic cards: ";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    PropertyData currentBitsPerPixel = mo.Properties["CurrentBitsPerPixel"];
    PropertyData description = mo.Properties["Description"];
    if (currentBitsPerPixel != null && description != null)
    {
        if (mo["CurrentBitsPerPixel"] != null && mo["CurrentHorizontalResolution"] != null)
            strGraphicCards += " **USED** " + description.Value + ", ";
        else
            strGraphicCards += description.Value + ", ";
    }
}
Serializers.Loggers.WriteNLog(strGraphicCards, eLogLevel.Trace);
```

and quite unexpectedly the result is:
[image]

Thanks for any help in understanding where the conundrum is

Patrick

Comment: No, this is the post I have taken my code from. The result is not correct (see above)

Comment: The query is different. You have linked another post in your question. (edit) I see, there is a second link. Please try with `Win32_DisplayConfiguration`

Comment: Woath thanks a lot! It works. Is that a general case solution? You might want to post is so that I can close the question